# TestNG classes expecting Exception.class

Tags: java, exception, testng

I have inherited some code from another team which uses

```
@Test (expectedExceptions = {Exception.class})
```

everywhere when the code might be throwing a more specific exception.

My understanding is that this is wrong because we are not expecting the right type of exception. But the current owners are saying that they have seen no issue because of this.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You should expect the type of `Exception` that is actually documented in the method you are testing. This documentation is either the method's signature itself (in case of checked exceptions) or the Javadoc (in case of unchecked exceptions). So, if the method declares to throw a general `Exception`, this is what you should expect in the test. And afterwards, redesign the tested method as declaring to throw `Exception` is a design flaw. :-) But if the method under test already documents a more specific exception, then you are right. Expect the specific one!

Comment: *But the current owners are saying that they have seen no issue because of this.* Just because they're not seeing an error, doesn't mean its the best approach to unit testing.  I'd imagine that they *wouldn't* see any issue with it if the class were behaving properly, but if the class started misbehaving, that misbehavior could be "hidden" by such a wide net of `Exception.class`.  I think your intuition is right, that 99% of the time you should be using a more specific exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is poor design, since it could be masking errors other than the one being tested for. As an example, suppose your code should throw a `SecurityException` on some operation but instead is throwing a `NullPointerException` because of a naive dereference. Your test would pass when it should fail.

You should always make your matchers as specific as possible, and in this case, that means the most specific exception class that applies.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is Parent class of all types of exception in java, so basically your test will pass if code throws any checked or unchecked exception. But its better to write unit test that will expect a particular type of exception which your code can throw. For e.g. let say your have a method to validateParam

```
public void validateParam(String param) throws SomeCustomValidationException {
  //suppose param is null , now this code will throw NullPointerException
  if (param.length() > 2) {throw new SomeCustomValidationException();}
}
```

and you call it like this

```
public void businessLogic(String param)  {
   try {validateParam(param);}
   catch(SomeCustomValidationException e){//show error dialog to the user} 
}
```

So although your unit test will pass but your business logic will not work as you expected